# Rules or coding guide to ease work to GCC compiler and to minimize optimization errors

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

I'am having problems with optimization in a bare metal C++ project for an ARMv7 embedded system. If execute my software with optimization options disabled ( GCC -O0 : nearly all optimizations disabled ) the software runs without problems, but if I enable optimization ( GCC -O1 ) the program stops working one or two minutes after booting.

As far as I know, removing optimization reduces compilation time and keeps all debug information in the binary, and disabling It is recommended to reduce the turn around time while developing or debugging . But the software should work in the same way ( maybe faster or with a lower flash footprint ) if I enable optimization, but in my case, if I enable optimization it hangs.

I suppose that real problem is that I'have any kind of error or bug in my software that becomes apparent when I enable optimization, but I've checked my code from all sides and I am not able to locate that error ( the debugger looses connection when the system hangs ). It seems that I do not interpret the code in the same way that the compiler does.

For that reason I'am thinking of rearranging all the source code to ease work to the compiler, but before starting I would like to know if exists any kind of rules or coding recommendations ( good practices guide ) to make the work easier for the compiler to avoid this kind of errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Errors, that occur with optimization enabled, are often a hint to undefined behaviour in your program. So the coding rules you should adhere to are the C++ standard. You should enable compiler warnings. If that does not help, you should try to localize the problem and post the problematic code here.

Comment: *"As far as I know, removing optimization reduces compilation time and keeps all debug information in the binary, and disabling It is recommended to reduce the turn around time while developing or debugging "*...  More likely enabling optimizations (i.e. `-O1` or `-O2`) increases compilation time, but produces a program that runs much faster (and a smaller binary) than without those flags passed.

Comment: Your first order of business should be to isolate where in your program the bad behavior is occurring. Start by adding printf or log statements to monitor the progress of your program.  Add unit tests that run on both non-optimized and optimized builds. Run a program like valgrind on your compiled code to find bugs that might be hidden by a debug build.

Comment: Or just reduce your code to a [mcve] and share it here on SO.

Comment: Never compile without optimization in gcc. The code is just horribly and it disables many important warnings as they require the analysis only done during optimization. Use `-Os` or `-O2`. If your compilation time is too much consider splitting the source into multiple compilation units so only the parts you change need to be recompiled during development.

Comment: If turning optimization makes the code fail then you most likely have UB in your code. Did you mark all MMIO registers volatile? Did you add memory barriers as required?